# XML PHP Login Error

Tags: php, xml, forms, authentication

I'm trying to make a login form with XML and PHP but always I get an  error. My HTML file:

```html
<form action="login.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="pass" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Login!" />
</form>
```

And my PHP file:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('users.xml');
$usr = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if(empty($usr)) {
    die('Please enter an username!');
} elseif(empty($pass)) {
    die('Please enter a password!');
}
$l_usr = null;
$pass_e = md5($pass);
foreach($xml->user->username as $username) {
    if($username == $usr) {
        $l_usr = $username;
    }
}
if(empty($l_usr)) {
    die('User Not Found!');
}
if(!$xml->user->$l_usr->password == $pass_e) {
    die('Wrong Password!!');
}

echo 'Hello, '.$l_usr;
```

Is my codes. It's not working. And users.xml file is like this:

```
<users>
<user>
    <username>doruk.ayar</username>
    <password>96b9c62c86f35c209c5b8c302ba34175</password>
</user>
<user>
    <username>mina.alpturer</username>
    <password>32250170a0dca92d53ec9624f336ca24</password>
</user>
<user>
    <username>efe.gormus</username>
    <password>32250170a0dca92d53ec9624f336ca24</password>
</user>
</users>
```

It's not working. When I write the correct username and correct password, it says "User Not Found!". Can someone help me?

**NOTE:** The passes:

```
doruk.ayar: 123pass
efe.gormus: pass123
mina.alpturer: pass123
```

Comment: any (special) reason you're not using a database? it's also a lot less work then text files and more secure.

Comment: You also should not be using MD5, you shouldn't be using this code at all, not if it's going live or is already live. You **will** get hacked.

Comment: Don't ignore my comments, again... **you will get hacked** then you'll come back crying to us saying: *"My site got hacked, what do I do??!!"*

Comment: you seem to be only responding to answers below. See the other, that's the one that's working. Go respond to him then and good luck getting your site back when it gets hacked. I'm outta here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've debugged your code and the user is found correctly but I've noticed another error in below part of your code

```
if(!$xml->user->$l_usr->password == $pass_e)
```

This return always NULL and operator "!" is useless here

```
$xml->user->$l_usr->password
```

I've fixed It writing more efficient and correct code

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('users.xml');
$usr = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if(empty($usr)) {
  die('Please enter an username!');
} elseif(empty($pass)) {
  die('Please enter a password!');
}
$pass_e = md5($_POST['pass']);
$valid=false;
foreach($xml->user as $userNode)
{
  if($userNode->username==$usr && $userNode->password==$pass_e)
 {
   $valid=true;
   break;
 }
}

if($valid==false)
{
  die('Wrong password or username');
}

echo 'Hello, '.$usr;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have error in XML file tag.you have missed close tag `</users>`

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
<user>
    <username>doruk.ayar</username>
    <password>96b9c62c86f35c209c5b8c302ba34175</password>
</user>
<user>
    <username>mina.alpturer</username>
    <password>32250170a0dca92d53ec9624f336ca24</password>
</user>
<user>
    <username>efe.gormus</username>
    <password>32250170a0dca92d53ec9624f336ca24</password>
</user>
</users>
```

**Updated**

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('users.xml');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
$usr = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$pass_e = md5($pass);


foreach($xml->user as $username) {

    if($username->username == $usr && $username->password==$pass_e) {
        echo "user found";
        break;
    } else{
    echo 'user not found';
    }
}




?>
```

Comment: It's saying user not found, but actually I'm writing the correct username and correct pass